# Is there a need for Setting an object to null after use in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there is a need for cleaning my objects following usage in JavaScript or there is some GarbageCollector that does that for me?
for example if this is my code:

```
function foo()
{
   var test = new testClass();
   console.log(test.getMessage());

   //the question is if there a need for the next line or not:
    test = null;
}

var testClass = function() {
    this.getMessage = function () {return "My MSG" };
}
```

Comment: good practice to do it manually. 

so set undefined

 test = undefined;

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript there is no need not need to care about garbage collecting process since it will be handled for you.

Comment: Still, a good practice to do it manually.

Comment: Agree, especially when it comes to operating on big sets of data within the app. Leaving unnecessary data in memory might slow it down but VM might be thinking that you still need some of them. +1